# ADDJUST traveling sine wave with rotating point on circle

Tags: geometry, nodes

ADDJUST traveling sine wave with rotating point on circle. I WANT THAT WHILE THE ICO SPFERE ROTATE ON CIRCLER and the sine wave moves to left or right at the same time the ico should me on the moving sine wave

https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZQ38NEaw/